# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $U \subseteq (X,d)$. Let $k \in (X,d)$. Prove.......

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $U \subseteq (X,d)$. Let $k \in (X,d)$.

Prove that $k \in U \Rightarrow d(U,k) = 0$, but the converse is not true.

Prove that $d(U,k) = 0$ iff $k$ is a contact point of $U$.

i.) The first one seems really obvious so I am unsure how to prove it.

ii.) By definition, $k \in (X,d)$ is a contact point of $U$ if $\forall r > 0, U \cap B_{r}(U) \neq \emptyset$. Then if $k$ is a contact point it would have to be in $U$ right but then by the first question $d(U,k) = 0$ This was just an idea.

The help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If it's obvious then prove it. Assume first that $k\in U$, then follow then *cmopute* $d(U,k)$ and show it is $0$. Then, give an example where where $d(U,k)=0$ but $k\notin U$. For ii) you can't use i) since your claim that "... Then if $k$ is a contact point it would have to be in $U$" is wrong. The example you'll find for part i) should make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition

$$d(U,k)=\inf_{u\in U}d(u,k)$$
so it's clear that if $k\in U$ that $d(U,k)=0$ and if $U=B(0,1)$ and $k=1$ we see that $k\not\in U$ and $d(U,k)=0$.

Now by the characterisation of the $\inf$ we have

$$d(U,k)=0\iff \forall \epsilon>0,\; \exists u\in U, d(u,k)<\epsilon\\\iff\forall \epsilon>0,\; B(k,\epsilon)\cap U\ne\varnothing\iff k\in \overline U$$